# Excessive drop shadow in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

If you look at the top cell, there is an excessive drop shadow while the one at the bottom has the intended drop shadow effect. The excessive ones disappears and becomes normal after scrolling it out of screen then coming back to it. I can not figure out what is going on with this.

Here is my drop shadow code in the tableview cell class :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: containerView.bounds)
    containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.1)
    containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    containerView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
  }
```

Please help and Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us images about this ?

Comment: the image is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. basically, I was using containerView.bounds for shadow path but the layer was drawn way too big because the cell started off big then shrunk based on device. The solution is to use constants. Anticipate the height and width and use CGRect.